# How to read through types of a struct in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, types, struct

I am trying to find the "types" of any given variables in different structs and be able to read them. (keep in mind this is psuedo code)

For Example:

```
#include "stream.h" //a custom stream reader class I made

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

/***** SERIES OF DIFFERENT STRUCTS ******/

struct asset
{
    char *name;
    int size;
    BYTE *data;
};

struct asset2
{
    char *lang;
    char *entry;
};

/*****************************************/


    void readAsset( Enumerable<struct> &istruct)
    {
        foreach( object o in istruct )
        {
            switch( o )
            {
                case int:
                    &o = _stream->ReadInt32();
                    break;
                case char:
                    &o = _stream->ReadChar();
                    break;
                case *:
                    &o = _stream->ReadInt32();
                    break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want it to be able to do the following:

```
asset a1;
asset2 a2;

readAsset( a1 );
readAsset( a2 );
```

and pass all the info from the file to a1 and a2.

I was wondering if there was a way in C/C++ to get the type of the data from any object in the struct then read based on that? is it possible with complex enums? Sorry for the bad code but I wanted it to be easier to understand what I'm trying to do.

Additional Info:

_stream is a pointer to a Stream class I made similar to Stream Reader in .Net It reads data from a file and advances it's position based on how big of data it was read.

I'll be happy to re-phrase if you don't understand what I'm asking.

Comment: There is no reflection in C++.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: That's not exactly true. There is compile-time reflection of a sort. In a template I can ask questions like "Does this type support a `push_back` operation?". But it's strictly at compile time, not run time. Rudimentary runtime 'reflection' is supported with the `typeof` operator. But it's not very powerful.

Comment: C or C++ languages do not support the concept of reflection, i.e. introspecting objects at runtime to determine is type and its structure. C++ supports a simple form of introspection using RTTI, but very much limited compared to what you're looking for. If you're interested in that, read more on `typeid`

Comment: @Omnifarious I could use that. it doesn't need to be that powerful just be able to identify int's, char's, or pointers (which I could always use char pointer[4] or int)

Comment: @user1425433: You are taking the wrong approach to solving your problem in C++. Please don't try to warp things in this way. The runtime type identification won't actually help you in this case anyway because there is no reliable way to get the variable's value in and out of the function without knowing its full type if the variable could be of a primitive type that has no base class. Consider using overloaded functions. That's what they're for.

Comment: There, I wrote something for you to show you how you might have a thing that automatically writes C++ serialization functions for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to iterate through the members of a structure without listing them all out.

You can iterate through something like a structure at compile time using `::std::tuple` in C++11.

You also can't really switch on type in that fashion. You can do it, but the way you do it is to have several functions with the same name that each take a different parameter type. Something like:

```
 void doRead(StreamType &stream, int &data)
 {
     data = stream.readInt32();
 }
 void doRead(StreamType &stream, char &data)
 {
     data = stream.readChar();
 }
 // etc...
```

Then you just call `doRead` with your structure member and *poof* the compiler magically picks the right one based on the type.

In C++, the way to solve the problem you're solving here is a serialization library. If you have control of both the format written and the format read, you can use something like [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) to do this relatively easily without having to write a lot of your own code.

Additionally, a couple of issues with your code. Do not use a leading `_` character in identifiers. Identifiers with a leading `_` are reserved for use by the compiler or standard library implementation. Many compilers have special keywords that are compiler specific language extensions that start with an `_` character. Using identifiers with a leading `_` character may result in your code mysteriously failing to compile with all kinds of strange inscrutable errors in some environments.

---

You can get something like a struct that is enumerable at compile time. But it's ugly:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

class asset : public ::std::tuple< ::std::string, ::std::vector<BYTE> >
{
 public:
   ::std::string &name()                   { return ::std::get<0>(*this); }
   const ::std::string &name() const       { return ::std::get<0>(*this); }
   ::std::vector<BYTE> &data()             { return ::std::get<1>(*this); }
   const ::std::vector<BYTE> &data() const { return ::std::get<1>(*this); }
};

void writeToStream(Stream *out, const ::std::string &field)
{
   out->writeString(field);
}
void writeToStream(Stream *out, const ::std::vector<BYTE> &field)
{
   out->writeInt(field.size());
   out->writeRaw(field.data(), field.size());
}

template <unsigned int fnum, typename... T>
typename ::std::enable_if< (fnum < sizeof...(T)), void >::type
writeToStream_n(Stream *out, const::std::tuple<T...> &field)
{
   writeToStream(out, ::std::get<fnum>(field));
   writeToStream_n<fnum+1, T...>(out, field);
}

template <unsigned int fnum, typename... T>
typename ::std::enable_if< (fnum >= sizeof...(T)) >::type
writeToStream_n(Stream *, const::std::tuple<T...> &)
{
}

template <typename... Tp>
void writeToStream(Stream *out, const ::std::tuple<Tp...> &composite)
{
   writeToStream_n<0, Tp...>(out, composite);
}

void foo(Stream *out, const asset &a)
{
   writeToStream(out, a);
}
```

Notice that there is no explicit `writeToStream` for the `asset` type. The compiler will write it at runtime by unpacking the `::std::tuple` it's derived from and writing out each individual field.

Also, if you have bare pointers, you're writing poor C++. Please write idiomatic, good C++ if you're going to write C++. This whole thing you want to do with runtime reflection is just not the way to do things.

That's the reason I converted your `char *name` to a `::std::string` and your size delimited `BYTE` array represented by your `size` and `data` fields into a `::std::vector`. Using those types is the idiomatically correct way to write C++. Using bare pointers the way you were is not. Additionally, having two fields that have strongly related values (the `data` and `size`) fields that have no behavior or any other indication that they're associated would make it hard even for a compiler that does introspection at runtime to figure out the right thing to do. It can't know how big the `BYTE` array being pointed to by `data` is, and it can't know about your decision to encode this in `size`.

Comment: yeah I get that but how would I list them all out? :/ I'm kind of looking for a way such as:
struct asset
{
 char *name;
 int size;
 BYTE *data;
};

asset a;

fread( (char *)a, sizeof(asset), 1, file );

Comment: @user1425433: You have to list all the individual members. Or do a lot of template magic and use the `tuple` template class for your data structures.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is something called [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) - which is:

> the ability of a computer program to examine
>   and modify the structure and behavior (specifically the values,
>   meta-data, properties and functions) of an object at runtime.

**C++ doesn't have that "*natively*".**

What I mean is - there have been some attempts at introducing some aspects of it - with varied degrees of success - which have produced some aspects of Reflection, but not "full" Reflection itself as you will get in a language like Ruby or so.

However, if you are feeling adventurous, you can try a Reflection library called [Reflectabit](https://bitbucket.org/dwilliamson/reflectabit):

To see if it might be worthwhile (which it might be considering your code), it is referenced here - which has quite a bit of examples on how to use the API:

http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/09/25/reflection-in-c-part-1-introduction/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The usual pattern in C++ is not to try and figure out what the members of the type are, but rather provide an operator, implemented by the implementor of the type, that is able to serialize/deserialize to disk.

You can take a look at, for example, the boost::serialize library. The usage is not too complex, you need to provide a function that lists your members in some order and then the library will take it from there and implement serialization to different formats.